# Using BCryptPasswordEncoder in android studio?

Tags: spring-boot, android-studio

Using BCryptPasswordEncoder to encode password spring boot , and I need to login from Android Application but no BCryptPasswordEncoder in android studio and cannot know the password to check ?

Answer (score 0):

add in build.gradle(:app) this 2

```
implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:5.7.2'
implementation 'commons-logging:commons-logging-api:1.1'
```